# Laravel 8 API call not returning validation errors correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-authentication, laravel-api

I am making the following call to my API routes using Postman everything works fine until I force a validation error. the error object returned doesn't contain the full list of validation errors instead it only has something like this:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"email":["validation.email"],"password":["validation.min.string"]}}
```

What I want is that instead of "validation.min.string" it should return the full error message.

Here is my controller method:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        $credentials['status'] = true;

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json('login success!');
        } else {
            return response()->json('login failure!');
        }
    }
```

Here is the screen shot of the postman request

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNKqY.png)

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Does the file `resources/lang/en/validation.php` exists? And if so, does the keys `email` and `min` exists ?

Comment: Thanks a lot  Clément Baconnier . you are right since I am not using views I had deleted the resources folder and with it the lang folder, silly me. thanks again.

Comment: I remember a tweet of Taylor Otwell proposing to move the lang folder one level upper for this exact reason. I believe, it already works if you move it. So `resources/lang/en` would become `lang/en`

Comment: I have posted my comment as answer to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As par my comment:

1. Ensure the file `resources/lang/en/validation.php` exists
2. If so, Ensure the keys `email` and `min` exists

As a side note:

You can move the folder `lang` at the top level and it will still work.
So `resources/lang/en` would become `lang/en`

Comment: I moved it and it works, I didn't know that. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create new FormRequest class and override below method in

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        $response = [
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $validator->errors()->first(),
        ];
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response, 422));
    }
```

Or use this code :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   // your validation rules
])->stopOnFirstFailure(true);

$validator->validate();
```

it will return only single validation message